# Matrix Vector multiplication in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am having a Matrix of size **D by D**  (implemented as List[List[Int]]) and a Vector of size **D** (implemented as List[Int]). Assuming value of **D = 3**, I can create matrix and vector in following way.

```
val Vector = List(1,2,3)
val Matrix = List(List(4,5,6) , List(7,8,9) , List(10,11,12))
```

I can multiply both these as

```
(Matrix,Vector).zipped.map((x,y) => (x,Vector).zipped.map(_*_).sum )
```

This code multiplies matrix with vector and returns me vector as needed. I want to ask is there any faster or optimal way to get the same result using Scala functional style? As in my scenario I have much bigger value of **D**.

Comment: Writing efficient and scalable matrix and vector operations is an extremely hard task. If you are going to extensively use these operations, you should seriously consider using a specialized library such as [nd4s](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/tree/master/nd4s) or [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze)

Comment: Variable naming convention in Scala is to start variables with lowercase letters. So use `vector` and `matrix` instead; besides `Vector` is a data type in Scala standard library and it is always a bad idea to name variables like that.

Comment: Another issue is that it is not clear if `List(1,2,3)` is supposed to represent a column vector or a row vector. Your code acts as if it is a column vector, but then you use the same `List(a,b,,,)` construct to define rows in your matrix.

Comment: @jrook I am considering it as column vector.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
def vectorDotProduct[N : Numeric](v1: List[N], v2: List[N]): N = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._

  // You may replace this with a while loop over two iterators if you require even more speed.
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining1: List[N], remaining2: List[N], acc: N): N =
    (remaining1, remaining2) match {
      case (x :: tail1, y :: tail2) =>
        loop(
          remaining1 = tail1,
          remaining2 = tail2,
          acc + (x * y)
        )

      case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) =>
        acc
    }

  loop(
    remaining1 = v1,
    remaining2 = v2,
    acc = Numeric[N].zero
  )
}

def matrixVectorProduct[N : Numeric](matrix: List[List[N]], vector: List[N]): List[N] =
  matrix.map(row => vectorDotProduct(vector, row))
```

Comment: I think my version of code is faster due to Lazyness.

Comment: @user12140540 This version just does the minimum amount of traversal, so lazyness doesn't help here. However, the only way to know which is faster is to benchmark. Otyer option would be to use the **ArraySeqs** with `tabulate`. Or consider using a specialized library as suggested in other comments.